# creating a global NSMutableSet

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-graphics

In reference to the answer of this SO question: [Keeping track of changes in a UIView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9318126/keeping-track-of-changes-in-a-uiview) 
I need help setting up the global aspect of the NSMutableSet. In my appdelegate.h file I've got this:

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
UIWindow *window;
ViewController *viewController;
NSMutableSet *statesTouched;
}
```

and this in my appdelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
statesTouched = [[NSMutableSet alloc]init];
[window addSubview:viewController.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}
```

In my viewcontroller.h file I'm adding the object like this:

```
[statesTouched addObject:touchedStateName];
```

but I'm getting an undeclared identifier for statesTouched. I've never tried putting something like this into my app delegate and I'm a little confused at how this should be working. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because is an instance variable of your `AppDelegate`, not your view controller. If you move the declaration and the initialization to your view controller, the error will go away. It would **not** make it a *global* variable, though, which is good if it works for you.

If it does not work for you, make the variable a truly global one: move the declaration out of the app delegate, and add `extern` keyword, like this:

```
extern NSMutableSet *statesTouched;
```

Now add the definition in the .m file, like this:

```
NSMutableSet *statesTouched;
```

Make sure the definition is outside the `@implementation` block.